# I am unable to fetch data from json

Tags: android, json

Here is my Json

```
{
    "2017": {
        "11": {
            "8": {
                "status": ""
            },
            "10": {
                "status": ""
            },
            "24": {
                "status": ""
            },
            "present": 0,
            "absent": 0
        },
        "12": {
            "1": {
                "status": ""
            },
            "2": {
                "status": ""
            },
            "present": 0,
            "absent": 0
        }
    }
}
```

In my above JSON 2017 is the year, 11 is the month, and 8 is the date .
I am not able to get 12 as month. I am just getting it till 11th month, and dates are coming in reverse order
This is what I am getting When I am fetching the data from json

12-03 10:26:23.592 18581-18581/? D/year: 2017

12-03 10:26:23.592 18581-18581/? D/month: 11

12-03 10:26:23.592 18581-18581/? D/16: 24

12-03 10:26:23.592 18581-18581/? D/title: A

12-03 10:26:23.592 18581-18581/? D/16: 10

12-03 10:26:23.592 18581-18581/? D/title: A

12-03 10:26:23.592 18581-18581/? D/16: 8

12-03 10:26:23.592 18581-18581/? D/title: P

and here is the code I has written to fetch this

```
try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
            Iterator iterator = object.keys();
            attendance_pojo pojo= new attendance_pojo();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String year = (String) iterator.next();
                pojo.setYear(year);

                Log.d("year", year);
                JSONObject obj = object.getJSONObject(year);
                Iterator iterator2 = obj.keys();


                while (iterator2.hasNext()) {

                    String month = (String) iterator2.next();
                    pojo.setMonth(month);
                    Log.d("month", month);
                    JSONObject ob = obj.getJSONObject(month);

                    Iterator iterator3 = ob.keys();

                        int datecntr=0;
                    while (iterator3.hasNext()) {
                        datecntr++;
                        String date = (String) iterator3.next();
                        pojo.setDate(date);
                        JSONObject ob1 = ob.getJSONObject(date);
                        Log.d("16", date);
                        String title = ob1.getString("status");
                        Log.d("title", title);
                    }
                    pojo.setDatecounter(datecntr);

                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}
```

Answer (score 1):

1)You are trying to iterate over an object containing two objects.  You probably want to define the months within an array as below:

2) The order of the json elements returned are random, they do not come in the specific order of the structure.

```
{
    "2017": [
        "11": {
            "8": {
                "status": ""
            },
            "10": {
                "status": ""
            },
            "24": {
                "status": ""
            },
            "present": 0,
            "absent": 0
        },
        "12": {
            "1": {
                "status": ""
            },
            "2": {
                "status": ""
            },
            "present": 0,
            "absent": 0
        }
    ]
}
```